# How to use android deeplink with custom DialogFlow action for google assistant?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to develop a feature to let user interact with my Android application using google assistant.

Due to my action is not available in [build-in intents](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/intents) (starting/stopping vpn service) i'm struggling to implement it using custom `DialogFlow` intent. (btw i have created [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153042508) to support it)

I have found [Deeplink helper](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html)

```
function startVpnHandler(agent) {
  let conv = agent.conv()
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: `speech`,
    text: `text`,
  }))
  conv.ask(new DeepLink({
    destination: 'App',
    url: 'deeplink.url',
    package: 'app package',
    reason: 'start vpn',
  }))
  agent.add(conv);
}
```

But unfortunately the assistant answer for this action is

> "App isn’t responding right now. Please try again later”

Firebase console outputs:

> DeepLink is *DEPRECATED*: Access will be by request only

I saw that the `Deeplink` is deprecated, but what is replacement for that?

I know that i'm able to create card response with the button which can contain deeplink, but
how can i invoke a deeplink directly for the `DialogFlow` custom action without additional user interaction?

I have researched a lot, someone suggests to use `FCM` and call it from webhook directly. But maybe you know another cleaner solution? And also i'm curios whether such action with implicit `FCM` calling will pass the google review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogflow isn't supported in App Actions.

It might not support all your use cases, but you could leverage [OPEN_APP_FEATURE BII](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) for some of your test queries.

[Stay tuned](http://g.co/appactions) for future updated to build customized intents.